# how to get latest datetime from multiple same dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

how do i get the latest datetime from multiple same dates in mysql?

```
SELECT start_time FROM times WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2013-01-27' AND '2013-02-02' ORDER BY start_time
```

this outputs:

```
2013-01-27 00:00:00 
2013-01-28 09:00:00 
2013-01-29 00:00:00 
2013-01-30 09:00:00 
2013-01-31 00:00:00     
2013-02-01 09:00:00      
2013-02-01 21:00:00      
2013-02-02 00:00:00
```

i want all this to output except i want the latest datetime for 2013-02-01
so it would output like this:

```
2013-01-27 00:00:00 
2013-01-28 09:00:00 
2013-01-29 00:00:00 
2013-01-30 09:00:00 
2013-01-31 00:00:00          
2013-02-01 21:00:00  <<<<<<<<    
2013-02-02 00:00:00
```

Comment: errrr, then you should do `...AND '2013-02-01' ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove redundant result set?

Comment: no that only outputs 1 result.. i still need all other dates but i dont want duplicate same dates just LATEST datetime for same DATE

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT didnt change anything.. just tried it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(start_time)
FROM times 
WHERE start_time BETWEEN '2013-01-27 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-02 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY DATE(start_time)
ORDER BY start_time
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b238/5)

Comment: @rubberchicken kindly tag this answer as the correct answer. :-)

Comment: im waiting for the seconds to countdown before i can :D -- now it let me do it ;) thanks again

Comment: @JW. thanks for the SQLFiddle, finally I can test SQL statments. I'm bookmarking the site.